# What is the name of this demo song for this keyboard?

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental, piano

I own this [keyboard](http://www.emediamusic.com/beginner-keyboard-piano-pack/play-piano-deluxe-pack.html), and I'm trying to identify its 95th demo song. I can't seem to find its name in the resources that came with the keyboard. I've also tried [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/) and keyboard search websites such as [Musipedia](https://www.musipedia.org/), but no luck. I ended up transcribing the song into sheet music, and my friend helped me identify that the first half is in G major and the second half is in A♭ major, so here is a [PDF](https://gist.github.com/samestep/6dd06a78a9f8e89155bcac3b6187a671) of that transcription. **What is the name of this song?**

Comment: Could it be this song list? https://www.floridamusicco.com/PDF/pianokeybdsonglist.pdf - then it is called "Skipping Tune"

Comment: @Stefan Unfortunately, no; assuming [these](https://youtu.be/mOjzmiRsS48) [videos](https://youtu.be/i2oLE-QnQk4) are the same Skipping Tune, that song is jazz, and isn't at all the same as the one I'm trying to identify. I believe that your list, which has 112 songs, is just a different list of songs from the 100 my keyboard has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is ["All Kinds of Everything"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Kinds_of_Everything). It was written by Derry Lindsay and Jackie Smith and, [performed](https://youtu.be/PK-p8l8fdNE) by the Irish singer Dana, it won the Eurovision Song Contest in 1970.